# sIFR problem with links (no longer functions)

Tags: drupal, sifr

I can't get links to work on this page with [sIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement): http://323creative.com/files/sample-sifr/

The browsers sees them but they can't be clicked.

More specifically:

- **Mac:** Firefox 3/3.5 doesn't (Flash 10) / Safari 4 does (Flash 10)
- **PC:** Firefox 2/3 does, Safari 3 does / IE6/7/8 doesn't (Flash 9 or
  10)

I've looked into all kinds of things like fixFocus and playing with wmode, etc and can't get to the bottom of a fix.

Anything I can try?

Comment: check it out again... they can be clicked and the browser opens the page here... they just don't look like links. :)

Comment: What browser/platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What module are you using for it?

Check the [Cufon module](http://drupal.org/project/cufon), it's pretty simple and nice to use.

It interfaces [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) to the Cufón JavaScript library. Cufón performs text replacement on web pages, using the canvas element and [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) to render fancy typefaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the links' container instead of the actual link itself. However, to do that, you'll probably have to make sure that each link or group of links has it's own container, maybe just with a class of .needs-sifr or something.

Comment: If I replace the link's container, won't the link go away/be replaced?